# Python: Is there a math placeholder NoneType

Tags: python

I'm looking for a 'placeholder' value which has the characteristics of None but does not throw up a 'TypeError' when appearing in mathematical statements. For example consider the following usage of None:

```
>> x = None
>> x**2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

What I would like is an alternative placeholder value 'lets call it 'mathNone' which is invariant under mathematical operations and functions. Eg:

```
>> x = mathNone
>> x**2
mathNone
```

Or more generally:

```
>> some_arbitrary_math_function(mathNone)
mathNone
```

Does anything like this exist? Is there anyway to write my own?

The application is for an acausal equation solver. I.e a system of *m* equations and *m+n* variables, where any *n* variables can be assigned and the remaining *m* variables are left as some placeholder and solved for. I could use any number for the placeholder but I want to guarantee that there will never be ZeroDivisionErrors or ValueErrors.

Comment: I think you'll have to write your own class with `__mul__`, `__add__`, `__sub__`, etc. methods that all return `self`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) ("not a number").  NaN is a special value in IEEE 754 floating-point, intended for just the sort of scenario you describe.  Arithmetic on NaN behaves as you request:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan
nan
>>> nan ** 2
nan
>>> nan + 2
nan
# etc
```

However, NaN behaves surprisingly in some situations, to the point where it may be more trouble than it's worth.  Its most troublesome characteristic is that *all comparisons* involving NaN are false: it is not part of the total order that one expects for ℝ:

```
>>> [ nan > 0, nan < 0, nan == 0 ]
[False, False, False]
```

In fact, it's not even equal to itself...

```
>>> nan == nan
False
```

(To test whether a value is NaN, use `math.isnan`.)  It also won't completely immunize you from errors, e.g.

```
>>> nan / 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

(This last may mean Python is not fully IEEE754-compliant, but basically *nothing* is fully IEEE754-complaint, so.)

Final note: `float('nan')` is the easiest way to create a NaN value in Python up to and including 3.4.  The standard library added a constant [`math.nan`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#constants) in Python 3.5.  In code that needed to run on multiple versions of Python, I would do this:

```
import math
try:
    nan = math.nan
except AttributeError:
    nan = float('nan')
```

Comment: Please write this as `math.nan` in Python 3.5

Comment: @NeilG Thanks, I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `inf` or `nan` fits your needs...

```
>>> x = float("inf")
>>> x**2
inf
>>> x = float('Inf')
>>> 10/x
0.0
>>> x = float("nan")
>>> x**2
nan
>>> y = float('NaN')
>>> 1/y
nan
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: division does not work with inf `10/x` gives a result of 0.0  You would need to use float('Nan') to get invariance.